# I did radio as an tab option but first one is working perfectly but second one is not working. Only one radio is working

Tags: javascript, html

I want 5 to 6 radio in a single form tag with the feature but different input field for all.
I am using 2 radio in same form. for suppose in my code if someone click on add new customer it will show a input field and when someone click on choose from existing it will show a different input field. Like this I added one more radio button that will change the input field using radio check but it's not working.

```js
function customerCheck() {
  if (document.getElementById('newCustomer').checked) {
    document.getElementById('newCustomerForm').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('existCustomerForm').style.visibility = 'hidden';
  } else {
    document.getElementById('newCustomerForm').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('existCustomerForm').style.visibility = 'visible';
  }
}

function toggleHiddenContent() {
  var hiddenContent = document.querySelector('.hidden-content');
  var readMoreBtn = document.getElementById('readMoreBtn');

  if (hiddenContent.style.display === 'none') {
    hiddenContent.style.display = 'block';
    readMoreBtn.textContent = 'Less Information';
  } else {
    hiddenContent.style.display = 'none';
    readMoreBtn.textContent = 'Add More Information';
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="row row1-new-service">
    <h2>Create Service Record</h2>
  </div>
  <section>
    <div class="row row2-new-service">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-12 addservice-col1">
        <h1>Customer Information</h1>
        <div class="inner-row col2-section">
          <!-- Customer Information Start HERE -->
          <div class="col2-section-col1" style="margin-bottom:100px;">
            <h2>Contact Information</h2>
            <p>You must enter customer information for service registration. To select from old customers, you need to click on the "Choose from existing customers" button.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col2-section-col2" style="margin-bottom:50px;">
            <form>
              <!-- Customer Ratio Buttons -->
              <label style="margin-right:10px; font-weight:600 !important;">
                                    <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:customerCheck();" name="customer" value="1" id="newCustomer" checked="checked">
                                    Add new customer
                                </label>
              <label style="font-weight:600; !important">
                                    <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:customerCheck();" style="font-weight:600;" name="customer" id="existCustomer">
                                    Choose from existing customers
                                </label><br>
              <!-- ./Customer Ratio Buttons -->

              <!-- Add New Customer Form -->
              <div id="newCustomerForm" style="visibility: visible" class="customer-form">
                <div class="form-group1" style="margin-top:0px !important;">
                  <label for="name"><span style="font-size:18px; font-weight:600;">Name Surname/ Address<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></span></label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control1" id="name" placeholder="Enter Customer Name or Company Name" name="name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
                </div>
                <!-- Add more input fields for new customer form -->
              </div>
              <!-- ./Add New Customer Form -->

              <!-- Choose Existing Customer Form -->
              <div id="existCustomerForm" style="visibility: hidden" class="customer-form">
                <div class="form-group1">
                  <label for="existingCustomer"><span style="font-size:18px; font-weight:600;">Select Existing Customer</span></label>
                  <select id="existingCustomer" class="form-control1">
                    <!-- Add options for existing customers -->
                  </select>
                </div>
                <!-- Add more input fields for existing customer form -->
              </div>
              <!-- ./Choose Existing Customer Form -->

              <!-- Add More Information Button -->
              <button type="button" id="readMoreBtn" onclick="toggleHiddenContent()" class="add-more-btn">Add More Information</button>

              <!-- Hidden Content -->
              <div class="hidden-content">
                <!-- Additional input fields -->
              </div>
              <!-- ./Hidden Content -->
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END USER START HERE -->
        <div class="inner-row col2-section" style="margin-top:-80px;">
          <div class="col2-section-col1">
            <h2>End user</h2>
            <p>If the product belongs to your dealer's customer, you can enter the name and surname information.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col2-section-col2">
            <div class="form-group1" style="margin-top:0px !important;">
              <label for="surname"><span style="font-size:18px; font-weight:600;">Surname</span></label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control1" id="surname" placeholder="Owner of Product Name and Surname" name="surname" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END USER END HERE -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 addservice-col2">
        <h2>Transactions</h2>
        <p>What do you want to do?</p>
        <div class="inner-row row inner-button">
          <button class="save-btn">Save</button>
          <button class="cancel-btn">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Here is no `java` involved. Do you mean `javascript'?

Comment: Yes, I mean JavaScript

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you delegate, then you can add a data-id on each radio and hide the one not selected

```js
document.querySelector(".content-wrapper").addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  const tgt = e.target;
  if (!tgt.matches("input[type=radio][data-id]")) return
  const id = tgt.dataset.id;
  document.querySelectorAll(`[name=${tgt.name}]`).forEach(elem => {
    const targetId = elem.dataset.id;
    document.getElementById(targetId).hidden = id !== targetId;
  })
});
```

```html
<div class="content-wrapper">
  <div class="row row1-new-service">
    <h2>Create Service Record</h2>
  </div>
  <section>
    <div class="row row2-new-service">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-sm-12 addservice-col1">
        <h1>Customer Information</h1>
        <div class="inner-row col2-section">
          <!-- Customer Information Start HERE -->
          <div class="col2-section-col1" style="margin-bottom:100px;">
            <h2>Contact Information</h2>
            <p>You must enter customer information for service registration. To select from old customers, you need to click on the "Choose from existing customers" button.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col2-section-col2" style="margin-bottom:50px;">
            <form>
              <!-- Customer Ratio Buttons -->
              <label style="margin-right:10px; font-weight:600 !important;">
                                    <input type="radio" data-id="newCustomerForm" name="customer" value="1" checked="checked">
                                    Add new customer
                                </label>
              <label style="font-weight:600; !important">
                                    <input type="radio" data-id="existCustomerForm" style="font-weight:600;" name="customer" value="0">
                                    Choose from existing customers
                                </label><br>
              <!-- ./Customer Ratio Buttons -->

              <!-- Add New Customer Form -->
              <div id="newCustomerForm" class="customer-form">
                <div class="form-group1" style="margin-top:0px !important;">
                  <label for="name"><span style="font-size:18px; font-weight:600;">Name Surname/ Address<span style="color:#ff0000;">*</span></span></label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control1" id="name" placeholder="Enter Customer Name or Company Name" name="name" aria-describedby="emailHelp" required>
                </div>
                <!-- Add more input fields for new customer form -->
              </div>
              <!-- ./Add New Customer Form -->

              <!-- Choose Existing Customer Form -->
              <div id="existCustomerForm" hidden class="customer-form">
                <div class="form-group1">
                  <label for="existingCustomer"><span style="font-size:18px; font-weight:600;">Select Existing Customer</span></label>
                  <select id="existingCustomer" class="form-control1">
                    <!-- Add options for existing customers -->
                  </select>
                </div>
                <!-- Add more input fields for existing customer form -->
              </div>
              <!-- ./Choose Existing Customer Form -->

              <!-- Add More Information Button -->
              <button type="button" id="readMoreBtn" onclick="toggleHiddenContent()" class="add-more-btn">Add More Information</button>

              <!-- Hidden Content -->
              <div class="hidden-content">
                <!-- Additional input fields -->
              </div>
              <!-- ./Hidden Content -->
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END USER START HERE -->
        <div class="inner-row col2-section" style="margin-top:-80px;">
          <div class="col2-section-col1">
            <h2>End user</h2>
            <p>If the product belongs to your dealer's customer, you can enter the name and surname information.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="col2-section-col2">
            <div class="form-group1" style="margin-top:0px !important;">
              <label for="surname"><span style="font-size:18px; font-weight:600;">Surname</span></label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control1" id="surname" placeholder="Owner of Product Name and Surname" name="surname" aria-describedby="emailHelp">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END USER END HERE -->
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 addservice-col2">
        <h2>Transactions</h2>
        <p>What do you want to do?</p>
        <div class="inner-row row inner-button">
          <button class="save-btn">Save</button>
          <button class="cancel-btn">Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use jQuery, it can do it all!

> Just ignore this, I need some sleep